# Database to store one row only

Tags: database, vb.net, database-design

I need to create a database which will store just three values from textbox on form1. Each time i click on button it will store over those files.

This is needed because i need to create the chart on report. And for creating the report i need to use database ( because there is no other way ).

So which is the best possible solution for this. For now I'm creating chart like this but it is impossible to set this chart on .rdlc MS Report form.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    With Me.chrtRegisterAvailability
        .Legends.Clear()
        .Series.Clear()
        .ChartAreas.Clear()
    End With

    Dim areas1 As ChartArea = Me.chrtRegisterAvailability.ChartAreas.Add("Areas1")

    'With areas1
    'End With

    Dim series1 As Series = Me.chrtRegisterAvailability.Series.Add("Series1")

    With series1
        .ChartArea = areas1.Name
        .ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie
        .Points.AddXY("Website Impressions", TextBox1.Text)
        .Points.AddXY("Social Media", TextBox2.Text)
        .Points.AddXY("Clicks", textbox3.text)
    End With

    Dim T As Title = chrtRegisterAvailability.Titles.Add("Visits by Traffic Source")
    With T
        .ForeColor = Color.Black
        .BackColor = Color.LightBlue
        .Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 9.0F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
        .BorderColor = Color.Black
    End With
    Dim legends1 As Legend = Me.chrtRegisterAvailability.Legends.Add("Legends1")
End Sub
```

Comment: So would you suggest me to use datatable ? I' tried like this #1.  #1.  Added DataSet    Add->New Item
#2.  Create DataTable1 on DataSet1
#3.  Added two columns  ValueA, ValueB both int16   
  [Picture 1](http://pokit.org/get/?5ca82e81e1f7656878382e85355cbe62.jpg) 
#4. Added two values by using this code on Form Load.

Comment: Dim workRow As DataRow = DataSet1.DataTable1.NewRow()
        DataSet1.DataTable1.Rows.Add(New Object() {270, 300})

#5. Added a ReportViewer on Form2 
#6. Created the Report and put the values from datasource on it.
http://pokit.org/get/?b8f4d4ac72d654156f49574559e0060b.jpg

When i run the program it won't show me the values on report :S :S :S

Comment: But you can't add the values from settings to chart on report ?

Can you /

Comment: No i have like 25 different values to transfer and edit on report. I almost finish my project and i stuck with this last step. I have three values on Form1 which i need to transfer on that report and represetn on pie chart. See this mine question on stackoverflow i opened day ago [Stackoverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278591/chart-from-form1-to-microsoft-report) , If you have a free time to help me with this i would appreciate it